# Grails: add children to parent with AJAX

Tags: ajax, grails, one-to-one

I have a simple 1:1 relationship:

```
class MyParentDomain{
  String name
  MyChildDomain onlyChild
}

class MyChildDomain{
  String name
}
```

Now on a form where I want to make a new parent "Mom", there will be a list with all the existing children.  Is there a current good-practice to add children on that same form?  I'm imagining a "plus" button next to the drop-down list of "onlyChild" where I could see a form for new "MyChildDomain".  I saw a link somewhere where people were talking about cracking this problem (will add the link as soon as I re-discover it).  Has this been done?  Is anyone doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this hasn't been generally applied to any templates or with a plugin (I might be wrong).

You *can*, however, use the "list" abilities that Grails has which allow you to submit a list of domain entity data and then build the list of child elements in the controller from the submitted data and persist that. I've never done this myself, however, so you will need to do a bit of digging on it.

As you may have guessed, attempting to create child entities on the fly via Ajax is likely not to work since the parent entity doesn't exist yet, so there's nothing to attach them to.